# Can we delete User properties from Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics has a 'User properties', when we created one, we have 2 fields: `name` and `description`. When this property is created, I just have one option, which is edit.

This edit option only gives permission to change the description but not to change the user property name.

Is it possible to delete this user property?

Comment: Yes, I am also looking for this answer. There only `Edit` Option once the property is saved

Comment: This is like some kind of a joke. I really don't understand why Firebase does not add "remove" option?

Answer (score 24):

## Since 2016:

No, not yet.

The official statement is: at the moment, your only options are to create a new project or to wait until we add the ability to delete slots.  No ETA on that yet.

from: Steve Ganem at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Z-dPnzcW_Gw

## 2021 Update:

- The feature is now called: **Custom Definitions**
- You cannot delete a custom definition
- You can **archive** a custom definition

[image: Firebase custom definition archive button in german]

Comment: this is correct, and SUPER lame, It is October of 2017 and they have STILL have not implemented this.

Comment: Still no ETA, but they said "deleting apps is being worked on an will be available in the near future" a year and a half ago.  So near future > 1.5 years... yeah.  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/Z-dPnzcW_Gw/-mHAopERGAAJ

Comment: Its 2018 now, still no `Remove` option.

Comment: jokes on you firebase..jokes on you. I also filed a ticket to the support and they answered that they, from the support, are also not able to delete UserProperties. wow

Comment: 2018 has only 2 months to go and still no deletion. WOW

Comment: Perhaps these properties are literally written on stone tablets and the backend scans them periodically... Can't believe Google would provide an API where you can't delete something you created... 2 years later

Comment: 2019 and still no delete option. WTF Firebase ?

Comment: Google, a multibillion dollar company, can't do simple CRUD :/

Comment: June 20198, nothing :)

Comment: See @mathew11's answer below.

Comment: End of August 2020, still nothing…

Comment: 2021, still nothing

Comment: Almost 5 years after i posted the Answer,   was wondering if it's now possible.  At least they added the feature to archive it

Answer (score 8):

It seems that an *archive* option has been recently added, it is also mentioned in the [docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#).

[image: firebase user properties]

Comment: From the docs: If you have reached your limit of 25 user properties and need to create new ones, you can archive the ones that are no longer relevant, and then after 48 hours, create a new one. During the first 48 hours after archiving a user property, you can restore it. After 48 hours, the user property is permanently archived. To restore a user property during the 48 hours after archiving, you set and register a new property with the same name per the instructions in the preceding section.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround. You can reset current analytics for the user like this.

```swift
FirebaseApp.configure()

Analytics.setUserID("tt")

// Register properties test1, test2,…test26 (the 26 will fail)
for i in (1...26) {
    Analytics.setUserProperty("test", forName: "test\(i)")
}

Analytics.logEvent("bang", parameters: [:])

InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID { (error) in
    InstanceID.instanceID().getID(handler: { (token, err) in
        Analytics.resetAnalyticsData()

        Analytics.setUserID("tt")

        // Now you can set new 25 properties
        for i in (26...30) {
            Analytics.setUserProperty("test", forName: "test\(i)")
        }

        Analytics.logEvent("bang", parameters: [:])
    })
}
```

This is handy in case you export events to BigQuery for example.